# Why is there is no Stack Exchange community to discuss general issues with smartphones?

Tags: feature-request

Recently I lost my mobile and came across a trivial problem of accessing my contacts and text messages through my laptop.

But instead of heading straight for a reliable Stack Exchange community, I had to sift through countless bogus blogposts and unreliable websites to get to a solution.

The question is, shouldn't we have a Stack Exchange Community where one can post general smartphone (or any mobile devices) troubles?

Comment: Why should there be such a site? How successful do you think such a site would be? Nothing is stopping you from suggesting such a site on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Why shouldn't there be? Because no one asked for one. In the same way, there is no Stack Exchange for clouds, sheep or rocks. There is a cost associated with creating a Stack Exchange.

Comment: I don't appreciate the label, by the way. This isn't conductive to discussion. I believe the question of why is legitimate - why don't you think it is?

Comment: If you would find your way through it. There are communities for Android, Apple and Windows phone each. But my point being, wouldn't it be desirable to have a database of solutions to problems that are independent of the embedded-os. They might even be specific to a particular build-model of the hardware. They might be specific even to an app. But independent of the OS.

And as I said, If you would find your way through it, maybe you would get what I am saying. Do you still believe no one needs it?

Comment: I disagree that there is a need for a general site of this sort - I disagree it would be generally useful, as most mobile questions pertain to specific devices and are not general. You are most welcome to prove me wrong by suggesting such a site, getting people behind it and getting it launched. That is the process to start new Stack Exchange sites, after all.

Comment: There was a proposal that covered consumer electronics, [Electronic Gadgets](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets) - but it didn't survive beta. IIRC a separate "consumer electronics" proposal suffered the same fate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A site like that would overlap with a few sites that we already have.

We have [Android Enthousiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com) for Android questions.
We have [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) where iPhone questions can be asked.
We have [Windows Phone](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com) for, well, Windows Phones.

If none of these are appropriate, then [Super User](https://superuser.com) also has a tag [mobile](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mobile), but that is only for interfacing between mobile devices and one's computer.

So, if your problem doesn't fit any of these categories, I'm afraid you're out of luck.

You could propose a new site on Area 51, as was pointed out in comments.

If I understand your question right, the original problem with your device has already been solved. But if you need immediate help and the sites mentioned above aren't appropriate, you could go here on Meta.SE and ask for a [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation).

Comment: I thought Android Enthusiasts was for Android Programming.

If that is not the case, it seriously needs a change of name.

Though, I still maintain, problems encountered with Users on Smartphones don't necessarily lend themselves to one of the three classification (Android, Apple and Windows).

Comment: Android programming is [off-topic](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on Android Enthusiasts; those questions  go on Stack Overflow under their "android" tag.

Comment: I will keep that in mind, the next time I have an Android Programming question.
Thank you, though.

Comment: You're welcome. I updated my answer in the light of your first comment.